# How do i change the int so that it has smaller field to choose random numbers

Tags: c++

```
//Computer Guess My nUmber Game

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); //randomizer
    int computerguess = rand() %100+1;
    int attempts=0;
    int useranswer;
    cout<<"Guess My Number Game \n\n";
    cout<<"Enter your secretnumber\n";
    cin>>useranswer;
    do
    {
        cout<<"I guess its "<<computerguess<<endl;
        ++attempts;
        if (useranswer<computerguess)
        {
            cout<<"Ur answer is too high mr.Computer\n";
            int computerguess = rand() %100+1;                  //need help here
        }
        else if(useranswer>computerguess)
        {
            cout<<"Ur answer is too low mr.Computer\n";
            int computerguess = rand() %100+1;                 // and here
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"CORRECT MR COMPUTER! You won in "<<attempts<<" attempts\n";
        }
    } while (useranswer!=computerguess);

    return 0;
}
```

I just need it to make the region of numbers which the randomizer chooses from smaller?

Comment: Change `rand() %100+1` to e.g. `rand() %10+1`. That will reduce the range from 1..100 to 1..10.

Comment: But i want it to change depending on the if so that when its too high it will not try to guess higher than the number it just enetered

Comment: Use variables instead of `100` and `1` then, to get the required range.

Comment: Use "it's" here.

Comment: You should introduce function `int randomInRange(int from, int to);`

Comment: How can i make that it uses the number it just tried for ex.if the number i entered is 46 and the randomizer says 67 it must say your answer is too high and then the 67-1 must be used for the randomizer next time.

Comment: intrandomInRange(int computerguess,int a);

Comment: inside your if () blocks you have `int computerguess = rand() %100+1;  ` Remember these declare a new local variable `computerguess` that has no relation to the same named variable in the outer scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the range smaller by changing the "%100" to "%10" where 10 is the range of numbers you want.

Basically, rand() generates a random number between 0 and (at least) 32767. "%" is modulo, which finds you the remainder left over after you divide this random number by 100, in your current code. So if you happen to randomly get 32767, then 32767 / 100 is 327 with 67 leftover. Therefore, 32767%100 is 67. Since modulo can result in zero and you presumably want to have a whole number, you add one so the range goes from 0-99 (since you can't have 100 leftover if you divide by 100) to 1-100.